# Python custom processes pool : How to wait one out of many processes?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I want to create my own process pool, something like :

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
NB_PROCESS = 10
procs = set()

def do_job(args):
    *** some processing ***

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        for p in list(procs):
            if p.is_alive():
                print(f'Proc {p.pid} running...')
            else:
                print(f'Proc {p.pid} terminated')
                procs.remove(p)

        for i in range(NB_PROCESS-len(procs)):
            job_args=get_job_from_db()
            if job_args:
                p = Process(target=do_job, args=(job_args,))
                p.start()
                procs.add(p)

        time.sleep(1)
```

I want to have always 10 processes running : I want to start another process as soon as ONE (not all) process has terminated.

Actually I coded an active wait by using `.is_alive()` but I find that not clean at all.

Note that I cannot use Queues because I need to wait the very last moment to decide what job to run.

I cannot use python `multiprocessing.Pool` because `Pool.join()` will wait all jobs to be terminated. In my case, I want to know if one worker is free before doing a `apply_async()`, I cannot see any method to do this

I cannot put the `job_args=get_job_from_db()` in `do_job()` as I am running a MySQL transaction : each worker may get the same job (concurrency problem)

How can proceed to wait until one process in a pool is terminated ?

Comment: So do you want to Stop it when some process return a result?? Its hard to understand your question. It seems that you posted some random basic code

Comment: I want to have always have 10 processes running : as soon as one has terminated, I want to start another one.

Comment: So you want a Pool! Check google or stackoverflow for examples

Comment: That is the first thing I have done of course : Pool.join() will wait all jobs are terminated, not one only. In my case, I want to know if one worker is free before doing a apply_async(), I cannot see any method to do this.

Comment: Then post that code, cause you are not using it and we are not magicians to know it.  And to wait Pool work you have to do pool.close() and pool.join()

Comment: pool.close() will stop accepting new jobs, I do not want that : I need to continue the processing on all the workers

Comment: Eric please check some example!! you have to append ALL work in pool and dont have to do more, it will execute X process at same time and auto execute next task when someone end. I will leave this question

Comment: maybe start a new pool, create the loop which checks if no alive pool then create new one

Comment: the main point is that I cannot spool jobs in advance : I want to manage priorities, so before running a new job, I have to pick in my database the one that has the highest priority. If I do all apply_sync() in the pool, as the processing is very long, the higher priority job coming meanwhile won't be executed at once. I need to keep the queue as short as possible. That the reason why I need to know at once when a process or a worker has terminated.

Comment: can u run the function `I have to pick in my database the one that has the highest priority`inside one of the processes? If so, You could loop inside each process for `job_args=get_job_from_db()` ?

Comment: I modified the example in my question.

Comment: I want the master process to choose the job, otherwise, has I am running transactions, all workers may choose the same job (concurrency problem).

Comment: What exactly is the problem with having a process pool of 10 and a job queue for them to consume? There's no way they will grab the same job if you use the `multiprocessing.Queue`.

Comment: @Paker : the main point is that I cannot spool jobs in advance : I want to manage priorities, so before running a new job, I have to pick in my database the one that has the highest priority. If I do all apply_sync() in the pool, as the processing is very long, the higher priority job coming meanwhile won't be executed at once. I need to keep the queue as short as possible. That the reason why I need to know at once when a process or a worker has terminated